# How to fix: rpi sd card partitions not recogized

Tags: sd-card, partition

I am trying to clone an image that I have been working on.  I have a 32G sd card.  When I plug it into my pc, windows sees it as 4 different drives.  There is a "Boot" drive, a "RECOVERY" drive, and then two other drives that I cannot access unless I format them.  Since I can't access them, I can't read the files to an image on my pc.  Has anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question: There is nothing wrong with the SDCard...

Drive Formats:

Windows is being windows centric.  Windows does not understand [disk drive formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting) that are not native to Windows.  [Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) separate a disk drive into essentially different disks.  You will need to use a Linux or other operating system which does understand these different disk drive formats in order to access them.  It is likely the Linux disk format Windows can not read is [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4).

All this said, there might be tools to read ext4 formatted partitions from Windows.  [This stackexchange question hits at such a tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows).

Drive Images:

Be aware that normally a drive image is agnostic to the content of the drive.  That is to say, a drive image tool operates with out regard to partitions, formatting or content of a disk drive.  When creating an image, a drive image tool simply copies all of the disk drive, including  unused spaces, to a file. Conversely, the tool can also write the image file to a new disk drive.

Be aware that the new disk drive needs to be at least as large as the old disk drive the image was made from.  Also, that the new disk drive will look exactly like the old disk drive.  For example, creating an image of a 8GByte SDCard and then writing that image to a 16GByte SDCard will create an 8GBByte.  The missing 8GBytes is still there, you just need a partitioning editing tool to reclaim it.

Summation:

It should not be necessary to have the disk drive partitions mounted in order to create an image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are trying to make a backup image of your SD card, it`s very easy:

Insert your SD card in Your reader and connect it to PC.

Download Win32DiskImager from : [Win32DiskImager download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download)

After installing , open it, then click on the folder icon, choose the path where you want to save your image backup file and give it a name (ie. sdbackup.img), chose the correct drive letter of your SD card then click on "read".

[image]

After a while you will have you SD backup image, it will have the same size of your SD card and normally it can be restored to another same size SD card.
If you want to shrink it and prepare it to be restored to a smaller SD card I have a post [Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=145712#p1254148) with the instructions.